# ASP.NET Core 2 Web API File Download Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm comparing copying files from a network share vs. downloading a file from an ASP.NET Core Web API using a .NET Core 2 console app for both. My API is just kestrel; no IIS. It is the default "new ASP.NET Core Web API" project with a new controller. No special settings.

The API version takes 1000-1500ms to download the same 21MB file ten times (simultaneously) and while the file share version takes less than 500ms. For the API version, the file it is copying is even stored on my local drive!

I'm surprised to find that the API version is so much slower. I feel like I must be doing something wrong. How can I make it faster?

```
    public static async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
            File.Delete(destinationFile);
        using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
        }
    }
```

vs.

```
    public static async Task<bool> GetFileHttpAsync(string sourceURL, string destinationFile)
    {
        if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
            File.Delete(destinationFile);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:56845/api/att/"))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        using (FileStream destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Jon\\Attachments\\4.PDF", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan);
        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "4.pdf");
    }
```